# Join data from different nodes by tag value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform

I have an input XML file with objects data.
Each object has points with name & value.
Each point has additional data in a different node.
The value of  is identical in both nodes.
I need to transform it to an XML that I will be able to import to my DB.
For each point I wish to have 1 record with value & additional value.
How can do it with XSL?

Thank you for your help

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Name>Object1</Name>        
        <Side_Left>
            <Point>
                <Name>A</Name>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Value>2</Value>
            </Point>
        </Side_Left>
        <Side_Right>
            <Point>
                <Name>C</Name>
                <Value>3</Value>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <Name>D</Name>
                <Value>4</Value>
            </Point>
        </Side_Right>
        <Side_Left_Additional_Data>
            <Point>
                <Name>A</Name>
                <Value>10</Value>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Value>20</Value>
            </Point>            
        </Side_Left_Additional_Data>        
        <Side_Right_Additional_Data>
            <Point>
                <Name>C</Name>
                <Value>30</Value>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <Name>D</Name>
                <Value>40</Value>
            </Point>
        </Side_Right_Additional_Data>

    </Object>
</Objects>
```

**Required Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Name>Object1</Name>
        <Point>
            <Name>A</Name>
            <Value>1</Value>
            <Addtional_Value>10</Addtional_Value>
        </Point>
        <Point>
            <Name>B</Name>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <Addtional_Value>20</Addtional_Value>
        </Point>        
        <Point>
            <Name>C</Name>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Addtional_Value>30</Addtional_Value>
        </Point>
        <Point>
            <Name>D</Name>
            <Value>4</Value>
            <Addtional_Value>40</Addtional_Value>
        </Point>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

Comment: I removed the `xsl:stylesheet` nodes from your XMLs because they made no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT-1.0 stylesheet which transforms your input XML to the output XML is the following. It consists of three `xsl:template`s handling each level of your input XML.

The XPath expression

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Side_Left/Point | Side_Right/Point" />
```

does handle all primary `Point` node-sets and copies them.

But the central XPath expression is

```
../../*[contains(local-name(),'Additional')]/Point[Name = $curName]/Value
```

which copies the relevant `Side_*_Additional_Data/Point/Value` value to the related `Side_*/Point` elements.

**So here is the full XSLT(Version 1.0):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/Objects">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object">
      <xsl:copy-of select="Name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Side_Left/Point | Side_Right/Point" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Point">
      <xsl:variable name="curName" select="Name" />
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />  
        <Addtional_Value>
          <xsl:value-of select="../../*[contains(local-name(),'Additional')]/Point[Name = $curName]/Value" />      
        </Addtional_Value>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output is as desired.**